# What happens when I use require('on/a/path/that/doesn't/exist') in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, require

I want to read require files dynamically based on condition say

```
var clientName= "something";
var file = require('../somepath/ + clientName);
```

but I want to ask what will it return if the path doesn't exist?
I tried to find using debugger but it goes berserk and ends the debugging!

Comment: It "returns nothing" since returning does not ever happen.

Comment: Prashant, the example you use suggests `require` in Node.js but you've tagged with RequireJS. The answers you got answer from a RequireJS standpoint but you commented about the `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error, which is a Node.js error, not a RequireJS one. So which is it? Are you asking about `require` in Node.js or about RequireJS. They are two significantly different things.

Comment: I was asking about require in node.js. Thanks for pointing it out.Had to read about it first

Answer (score 1):

It will end with Not Found error. This error will be raised also by the require. You can catch this errors globaly. Check this url http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#requireargs

Comment: thanks.. it is throwing error of MODULE_NOT_FOUND. I resolve the problem by putting it in a try catch block

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default error handler of `requirejs` and play around with it to see what is happening

```
require.onError=function customErr(err){console.log('Custom:'+err)};
require(['../somedummyfile'])
```